# PHP String Concatenate issue

Tags: php

Output of below PHP string is not correct. It's displaying additional ( "> ) at end. Please help that what wrong I am doing?

```
$part2 = HTMLentities('<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php print($_SESSION["muser"]."-".$_SESSION["mpass"]);?>">');
print $part2;
```

Thanks, KRA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already in PHP mode, you should just use string concatenation instead of `<?php ?>` syntax; this example splits up the html creation and the escaping part.

```
$html = '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["muser"] . "-" . $_SESSION["mpass"]) . '">';

$part2 = htmlentities($html);
print $part2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is an additional > at the end.
Try this:

```
$part2 = HTMLentities('<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php print($_SESSION["muser"]."-".$_SESSION["mpass"]);?>"');
print $part2;
```

Comment: It's end tag for input tag. If I remove it, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of what you're looking for:

```
$part = '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . htmlentities($_SESSION['user'] . '-' . $_SESSION['mpass']) . '" />';
```

You've got a lot of poor PHP syntax in your example.

- We use `<?php` tags to escape out of HTML into PHP. When you have a PHP file, one way you could think about it is that you really have an HTML document - but one that you can add `<?php` tags to write PHP code in. In you're example you are trying to print HTML from within PHP, which can get admittedly complex. You are already in a PHP block, so you don't need to use the opening `<?php` tag.
- When concatenating strings to store in a variable, you don't need to use the `print` function. The `print` function is used to write text to the screen. You can just use the variables name as in the example I wrote to combine the strings.
- `htmlentities` is used to render any HTML in your string into text. We use `htmlentities` to keep unknown (user-entered) data from modifying our HTML. It would be a good idea to use htmlentities on the $_SESSION variables like I did above to make sure they don't break our `input` tag with invalid HTML. Using it on the entire string would just print your HTML as if it were raw text.

Here's a way to write it from outside of a PHP block:

```
<?php
    // initial PHP code
?>

<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user'] . '-' . $_SESSION['mpass']) ?>" />

<?php
    // continue PHP code
?>
```